# Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allow Multiple Origin Domains/ Subdomain using Traefik

Tags: header, traefik

Is there a way to allow multiple cross-domains using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header  using Traefik?

I'm aware of the *, but it is wildcard. I really want to allow just a couple domains.

As an example, something like this:

`traefik.http.middlewares.pa.headers.customresponseheaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'http://domain1.example, http://domain2.example'`

Is it possible to specify multiple domains/subdomains or am I stuck with just one?

The purpose of using this is for cookie based operations, where ui is hosted in `abc.example.com`, where credentials are set to `include`. In traefix the settings are with below configurations, hosted at `xyz.example.com`

```
  traefik.http.middlewares.pa.headers.customresponseheaders.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'content-type,realm'
  traefik.http.middlewares.pa.headers.customresponseheaders.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS'
  traefik.http.middlewares.pa.headers.customresponseheaders.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 'true'
  traefik.http.middlewares.pa.headers.customresponseheaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'http://abc.example.com'
```

But i have many UIs like `efg.example.com` and `pqr.example.com`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No currently I suppose.

[Issue reported](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/3686)

[Corresponding PR](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/1292)